# Как создать указатель на массив объектов?

Tags: c#, ооп, указатели, unsafe

Есть класс Person.
Создаем массив объектов класса Person:

```
Person[] Company = new Person[qty];
```

Вопрос: как создать указатель на массив объектов в C#?

```
Person* cmpPtr = Company -> Компилятор ругается;
```

В сборке проекта явно указал, что будет использовать небезопасный код.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Person
{
    public:
    int wagee_rate(){
    switch(position){
            case 1: wage_rate = 1500;break;
            case 2: wage_rate = 2500;break;
            case 3: wage_rate = 3500;break;
            case 4: wage_rate = 4500;break;
            case 5: wage_rate = 5500;break;
            case 6: wage_rate = 6500;break;
            default: wage_rate = 0;

        }

}
    private:
    int position,wage_rate,total,bonus;
    string name;
    public:
    Person()
    {


        position = 0;
        total =0;
        name = "";
        wage_rate=0;



    }

    public: 
    void set_worker(string new_name, int new_position)
    {
        name = new_name;
        position = new_position;
    }
    void get_worker()

    {   
        string person;
        switch(position){
            case 1: person = "specialist";break;
            case 2: person = "specialist1";break;
            case 3: person = "specialist2";break;
            case 4: person = "specialist high";break;
            case 5: person = "Chief";break;
            case 6 : person = "Direcotr";break;
            default : person = " ";
        }

        cout<<"Worker position is "<<person<<endl;
        cout<<"Worker name is "<<name<<endl;
        cout<<"Worker wage_rate is "<<wage_rate<<endl;
        cout<<"Worker bonus is"<<bonus<<endl;
        cout<<"Worker total salary is"<<total<<endl;

    }

    public:
    void set_bonus(float new_bonus)
    {
        bonus = new_bonus;
    }

    public:
    float get_bonus()
    {
        return bonus;   
    }   

    public:
    void set_total(float new_total)
    {
        total = wage_rate + bonus;
    }

    public:
    float get_total()
    {
        return total;   
    }

    public:
    int get_wage_rate()
    {
        return wage_rate;
    }

~Person(void)
{
    cout<<"destructed"<<endl;
}
};





void Show_all(Person *,int n);  
float averrage=0;   


int main()
{
int n = 0,position = 0;
string name;
cout<<"Enter the number of workers"<<endl;
cin>>n; 
Person organization[n];
Person *o_ptr = organization;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)//filling object array
{
cout<<"Enter the name and position"<<endl;
cin>>name;
cin>>position;
(o_ptr + i)->set_worker(name,position);
(o_ptr + i)->wagee_rate();
}


float tmp=0;//averrage
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
tmp += (o_ptr+i)->get_wage_rate();  
}

averrage = tmp/n;

float bonus;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)//calculating bonus
{
tmp = (o_ptr + i)->get_wage_rate();
if(tmp<averrage)
    tmp*=0.5;
else
tmp*=0.3;
(o_ptr+i)->set_bonus(tmp);

}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)//calculating total salary
{
(o_ptr+i)->set_total((o_ptr+i)->get_bonus());   
}

Show_all(o_ptr,n);  //showing info about all workers
}


void Show_all(Person *work_ptr,int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i<n)
    {
        (work_ptr + i)->get_worker();
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам `unsafe`?

Comment: Блок кода или метод, в котором используются указатели, помечается ключевым словом unsafe. Или здесь это не нужно?) Но все равно вопрос остается открытым =(

Comment: Зачем вам указатель? В C# они не нужны практически никогда.

Comment: Это университетское задание, нужно сделать именно с указателями, но можно писать и на плюсах или другим ооп-языках. На плюсах я могу ее написать, но хочу на Шарпах =) Так сказать, я однолюб)

Comment: В C# невозможно объявить указатель на ссылочный тип. Всё-таки объясните, зачем это вам понадобилось. Возможно, есть другие пути. Хинт: [GCHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ясно. Откройте учебник C#, прочитайте первые страницы про ссылочные типы. Далее просто используйте ссылки и забудьте про указатели. Хинт: ваша переменная `Company` в C# равноценна указателю в C++.

Comment: http://rgho.st/private/7k2tRgYwY/80f9ce788384e569cc68161a63c1774f

Написал данную программу на C++. Хотел переделать под C# тоже с указателями. Оказалось, что это не так уж и легко =). Программа реализует начисления заработной платы сотрудникам фирмы.

Comment: А зачем вам именно указатель? Чем ссылка не подходит? Если преподаватель говорит «сделайте с указателями», скажите ему, что в C# вместо указателей ссылки.